# Medium longspear used by a large creature

Tags: dnd-3.5e

What happens when a Large creature use a medium sized longspear ?

1st question: Can he use the Longspear in 1 hand ?

2nd question: What happens to the reach of the Longspear, can he use it only at 10' or can he use it at 5' too since he is larger after all ?

3rd Can he still decide to use it using 2 hands ?

Answer (score 9):

A medium longspear is one size category smaller than a large creature. Therefore the large creature treats it as a one-handed weapon, but still takes a −2 penalty to attack rolls when using it as such.

It works like a one-handed weapon in all respects, which means he can use it in one or two hands at his option. If he uses two hands, he gets 1½ Str to damage, and improved damage from Power Attack.

As for what reach he has with it, a large creature has a 10-ft. reach naturally (and can still attack inside this reach). A reach weapon for a large creature allows it to threaten at 15 ft. and 20 ft., but not at 5 ft. or 10 ft., its usual reach. However, as a smaller weapon than one designed for the large creature, the longspear loses its reach property, per *Rules Compendium*:

> A wielder gains no reach from a reach weapon that is too small.

<sup>(Note that aside from this point, weapon size has no effect on reach.)</sup>

Thus, the large creature threatens his normal reach with the medium longspear, i.e. 5 ft. and 10 ft., not his “reach weapon” reach.